# Loop through arc and pop values in different thread

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-warp

I'm trying to implement a shared state (`arc`) for a Warp route. Given this main function:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let ack_vec: Vec<api::Acknowledgement> = Vec::new();
    let arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(ack_vec));

    // GET /call/:id
    let call = warp::get()
        .and(warp::path("call"))
        .and(warp::path::param())
        .map({
            let queue = arc.clone(); // clone handle outside move

            move |id: u32| {
                let ack = api::Acknowledgement::new(id);
                let mut queue = queue.lock().unwrap();
                queue.push(ack);
                println!("pushed to queue: {:?}", queue);

                Ok(warp::reply::json(&id))
            }
        });

    let routes = call
        .with(warp::trace::request());

    warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 4000)).await;

    // problem starts here
    loop {
        let queue = arc.clone(); // clone the handle
        let mut queue = queue.lock().unwrap();

        println!("popped from queue: {:?}", queue.pop());
    }
}
```

Right now, if I hit the `/call` route I can see the `Acknowledgement` is added to the queue.

The `loop` at the end is supposed to pop each value from the queue as they're added. Right now it does nothing.

I've tried wrapping it in a `tokio::spawn` and still no result (nothing is printed to stdout).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you expect enter in your loop if you are waiting serving the request in your function ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Stargateur's comment I realised what I was doing wrong. Here's a working prototype should anyone else get stuck at a similar place.

```
std::thread::spawn(move || {
    loop {
        let two = std::time::Duration::from_secs(2);
        std::thread::sleep(two);

        let queue = arc.clone(); // clone handle outside move
        let mut queue = queue.lock().unwrap();
        println!("queue: {:?}", queue);

        while let Some(ack) = queue.pop() {
            println!("ack popped: {:?}", ack);
        }
    }
});

warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 4000)).await;
```